# How to subtract one indicator from another?

Tags: pine-script

I am using two indicators. These are Pine Script custom indicators written by someone else.

Are there any ways to create a third indicator which is one minus the other?

Stewart

I've looked for options in the UI and can't see anything feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would only be possible if the source codes are available. In that case, you would create one indicator and add both source codes in there, then do whatever operation you want to do.

Comment: Thank you. I feared that might be the case. I was hoping there would be some trick to reference the indicator script, rather than repeating it.